# How to pass Dynamic column name one by one in mysql Update query using java spring?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

```
 public static final String UPDATE="update basic_structure.time_table set #{b_id}=#{a_id} where days='MON'"; 

  @Update(UPDATE)
 int update(@Param("b_id") String b_id,@Param("a_id") String a_id);
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not enough information for us to understand what you are asking.  Please clarify.

Comment: i want to pass dynamic values one by one  instead of #{b_id}.I am trying to  pass database column name (b_1,b_2,b_3....).Here b_1,b_2 are the database column names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of passing dynamic column name to query you can use `dynamicUpdate=true` or `dynamicInsert=true`

so hibernate will update only those column which are modified.

e.g

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "<table_name>")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(
        dynamicUpdate = true
```

xml

```
<class ... table="<table_name>" dynamic-update="true">
```